# starting a daily time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a daily  time series about number of visitors on the web site. my series start from `01/06/2014` until today `14/10/2015` so I wish to predict number of visitor for in the future. How can I read my series with R? I'm thinking:

```
series <- ts(visitors, frequency=365, start=c(2014, 6))
```

if yes,and after runing my time series model `arimadata=auto.arima()` I want to predict visitor's number for the next 6o days, how can i do this?

```
h=..?
forecast(arimadata,h=..),
```

the value of `h` shoud be what ?
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I suggest to go and check out the package developers Rob H. Hyndmans website Examples (http://robjhyndman.com/talks/MelbourneRUGexamples.R)

Comment: @WD11 thanks for your link, but i have not found an example like my dataset

Comment: make a search for "h =" on that site there you will find examples for 30 days and/or 12 months 
# Exponential smoothing; 
fit1 <- ets(beertrain, model="ANN", damped=FALSE); 
fit2 <- ets(beertrain); 

fcast1 <- forecast(fit1, h=8); 
fcast2 <- forecast(fit2, h=8);

Comment: here you have monthly data forecasted 8 months into the future ... 
have alook at the beertrain timeseries (ts) object and later on compare it to the fcast forecast object ... modify the idea according to your needs; there is also an ARIMA model somewhere in there; 
i.e. my guess would be h = 60 based on your info ...

Answer (score 49):

The `ts` specification is wrong; if you are setting this up as daily observations, then you need to specify what day of the year 2014 is June 1st and specify this in `start`:

```
## Create a daily Date object - helps my work on dates
inds <- seq(as.Date("2014-06-01"), as.Date("2015-10-14"), by = "day")

## Create a time series object
set.seed(25)
myts <- ts(rnorm(length(inds)),     # random data
           start = c(2014, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j"))),
           frequency = 365)
```

Note that I specify `start` as `c(2014, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j")))`. All the complicated bit is doing is working out what day of the year June 1st is:

```
> as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j"))
[1] 152
```

Once you have this, you're effectively there:

```
## use auto.arima to choose ARIMA terms
fit <- auto.arima(myts)
## forecast for next 60 time points
fore <- forecast(fit, h = 60)
## plot it
plot(fore)
```

[image]

That seems suitable given the random data I supplied...

You'll need to select appropriate arguments for `auto.arima()` as suits your data.

Note that the x-axis labels refer to 0.5 (half) of a year.

### Doing this via **zoo**

This might be easier to do via a `zoo` object created using the **zoo** package:

```
## create the zoo object as before
set.seed(25)
myzoo <- zoo(rnorm(length(inds)), inds)
```

Note you now don't need to specify any `start` or `frequency` info; just use `inds` computed earlier from the daily `Date` object.

Proceed as before

```
## use auto.arima to choose ARIMA terms
fit <- auto.arima(myts)
## forecast for next 60 time points
fore <- forecast(fit, h = 60)
```

The plot though will cause an issue as the x-axis is in days since the epoch (1970-01-01), so we need to suppress the auto plotting of this axis and then draw our own. This is easy as we have `inds`

```
## plot it
plot(fore, xaxt = "n")    # no x-axis 
Axis(inds, side = 1)
```

This only produces a couple of labeled ticks; if you want more control, tell R where you want the ticks and labels:

```
## plot it
plot(fore, xaxt = "n")    # no x-axis 
Axis(inds, side = 1,
     at = seq(inds[1], tail(inds, 1) + 60, by = "3 months"),
     format = "%b %Y")
```

Here we plot every 3 months.

Comment: ,thanks very much for your good explanation, just i have a question what does means 2015.5 in the graph ?how can i get the exaclty date  format yy/mm/dd? thanks in advance

Comment: Gavin Simpson :thanks for your rapid and your good explnation

Comment: It means half a year (6 months). Getting nicer axis labelling is probably easier with a **zoo** object.

Comment: Gavin Simpson:thanks for your help , have you any idea about how can I intrepret acf and pacf plot ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, this saved me a lot of headache. Just to extend the answer a bit further, you can treat the 'zoo' series as a regular time series data. I applied it successfully with Naive, HoltWinters, and SES. Template code below:
## Create a daily Date object - helps my work on dates
inds <- seq(as.Date("2014-06-01"), as.Date("2015-10-14"), by = "day")

## create the zoo object as before
set.seed(25)
myzoo <- zoo(rnorm(length(inds)), inds)

## use auto.arima to choose ARIMA terms
fit <- auto.arima(myzoo)
## forecast for next 60 time points
fore <- forecast(fit, h = 60)

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson . Do I need to specify the 'day' even if I'm importing a csv data and the data includes dates?

Comment: @jackDanielle If you use the **zoo** version then no you don't need to specify the day. At the top of the answer I created a vector of dates `inds` which I pass as the indices to `zoo()` along side the data. Your dates in the CSV file should take the place of `inds` in the example using `zoo()`.

Answer (score 11):

Time Series Object does not work well with creating daily time series. I will suggest you use the `zoo` library.

```
library(zoo)
zoo(visitors, seq(from = as.Date("2014-06-01"), to = as.Date("2015-10-14"), by = 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear sample. Just to extend this answer further now you can treat the 'zoo' series as a regular time series, like as in: 
plot(myzoo), or 
## use auto.arima to choose ARIMA terms
fit <- auto.arima(myzoo)
## forecast for next 60 time points
fore <- forecast(fit, h = 60)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I created a time series when I was given some daily observations with quite a few observations missing. @gavin-simpson gave quite a big help. Hopefully this saves someone some grief.

The original data looked something like this:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(42)
minday = as.Date("2001-01-01")
maxday = as.Date("2005-12-31")
dates <- seq(minday, maxday, "days")
dates <- dates[sample(1:length(dates),length(dates)/4)] # create some holes
df <- data.frame(date=sort(dates), val=sin(seq(from=0, to=2*pi, length=length(dates))))
```

To create a time-series with this data I created a 'dummy' dataframe with one row per date and merged that with the existing dataframe:

```
df <- merge(df, data.frame(date=seq(minday, maxday, "days")), all=T)
```

This dataframe can be cast into a timeseries. Missing dates are `NA`.

```
nts <- ts(df$val, frequency=365, start=c(year(minday), as.numeric(format(minday, "%j"))))
plot(nts)
```

[image: holey sin wave]

Answer (score 1):

```
series <- ts(visitors, frequency=365, start=c(2014, 152))
```

152 number is 01-06-2014 as it start from 152 number because of frequency=365
To forecast for 60 days, h=60.

```
forecast(arimadata , h=60)
```